# Join mysql tables twice on 2 columns = 1 column

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains messages. The messages are stored in one table, the user information is stored in another. In the message table, there is an author_id column which represents the user_id of the author from the user table, there are all the message columns, and there is a to_address which represents a concatenation of "u_" + user_id from the user table. Is there any that I can join these two tables, so that it display the username instead of ID in BOTH the author_id AND to_address.

I've tried

```
SELECT  username, ..., username
  FROM msgs
    INNER JOIN users
      ON user_id=author_id AND concat("u_",user_id)=to_address;
```

with obvious error
I've tried using subqueries such as

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT username 
      FROM users
        INNER JOIN msgs
          ON user_id=author_id
  ) AS "From",
  ( SELECT username
      FROM users
        INNER JOIN msgs
          ON CONCAT("u_",user_id)=to_address
  ) AS "To",
  ( SELECT timestamp(message_time) FROM msgs
  ) AS "Sent",
  ( SELECT message_subject FROM msgs
  ) AS "Subject",
  ( SELECT message_text AS "Message" FROM msgs
  ) AS "Message"
```

and got "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Is there any way that I can do this successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was just working on that. Needless to say, I'm not very familiar with StackOverflow.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. It's quite useful to read the help before using something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    from_user.username AS "From",
    to_user.username AS "To",
    timestamp(msgs.message_time) AS "Sent",
    msgs.message_subject AS "Subject",
    msgs.message_text AS "Message"

FROM msgs

INNER JOIN users AS from_user
ON msgs.author_id = from_user.user_id

INNER JOIN users AS to_user
ON msgs.to_address = CONCAT("u_", to_user.user_id);
```

Basically, you join the `users` table to the `msgs` table twice, giving each instance of the table a different name and a different join condition.  Then you can pick a specific column out of a specific instance of the `users` table.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding the structure right, "INNER JOIN users AS from_user" Is that basically creating a temporary table? It worked perfectly, just trying to see if I understand each part.

Comment: normaly no, its just use the same table twise, to be sure run EXPLAIN infront of the select and see what mysql work the querry

Comment: @Morph: in a sense, every `SELECT` results in a temporary table (though not in the sense of an explicitly declared `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`). In RDB, you have scalars, tuples (rows) and relations (tables). Everything that has a value is one of those; the value of a `SELECT` is a relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like

```
SELECT msgs.*,
       authors.whatever,
       addresses.to_address
  FROM msgs
  JOIN users AS authors ON msgs.author_id = authors.id
  JOIN users AS addresses ON msgs.address_id = addresses.id
```

My query is perhaps imprecise but you can probably see what I'm doing here.

As an aside, I would recommend [not abbreviating msgs](http://jasonswett.net/blog/save-time-by-thinking-less-not-by-typing-less/) and [using singular table names](http://jasonswett.net/blog/why-database-table-names-should-be-singular/).

Comment: It was installed this way from a script. I didn't actually design the table layout. Changing it would require editing WAY too much on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins as you want to  get two separate users:

```
select f.username, t.username
from msgs m
inner join users f on f.user_id = m.author_id
inner join users t on concat("u_", t.user_id) = m.to_address
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the username associated with both the "author_id" and the "to_address", using correlated subqueries, instead of using JOIN. (Using a JOIN is the usual approach, but an approach using a correlated subquery gives you some additional flexibility.

```
SELECT (SELECT u.username 
          FROM users u 
            ON u.user_id = CONCAT("u_",u.user_id) = m.to_address
         ORDER BY u.username LIMIT 1
       ) AS to_username
     , (SELECT a.username 
          FROM users a 
            ON a.user_id = m.author_id
           ORDER BY a.username LIMIT 1
       ) AS author_username
     , m.*
  FROM msgs m
```

NOTE: this differs a bit from an INNER JOIN in that this will return a row from msg when a matching username is not found for the to_address or the author_id.)

NOTE: this assumes that user_id is unique in the users table.

NOTE: if the username column is NOT NULL in the users table, then you can emulate the INNER JOIN, and NOT return a row if a matching username is not found for the author_id or to_address by adding

```
HAVING to_username IS NOT NULL
   AND author_username IS NOT NULL
```