# How to join 2 columns in a SQL table to one column in another SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using MYSQL. I have two tables in my database.

Table 1: ‘courseTable’ has two colums:

```
courseId
courseName
```

Table 2: ‘prereqTable’ has two colums:

```
courseId
prereqCourseId
```

Both columns in table 2 correspond to courseId in table 1. I am trying to run a query that will result in a table that contains the courseName for the courseId and the courseName of the prereqCourseId.

I am stuck here:

```
SELECT `course`.courseName, `prereq`.prereqCourseId FROM `course`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `prereq`
ON `course`.courseId = `prereq`.courseId
```

Comment: just join to the same table twice..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join mysql tables twice on 2 columns = 1 column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567815/join-mysql-tables-twice-on-2-columns-1-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the course table twice with referecing to prereqTable table

```
SELECT a.courseName,c.courseName
FROM courseTable AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN prereqTable AS b ON a.courseId=b.courseId
LEFT OUTER JOIN courseTable AS c ON b.prereqCourseId=c.courseId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join the same table twice, you have to use aliases.

```
SELECT p.name AS parent, c.name AS child
  FROM relations AS r
  LEFT JOIN nodes AS p
    ON(p.id=r.parent)
  LEFT JOIN nodes AS c
    ON(c.id=r.child )
```

The `AS` are optional but recommended, as it improves readability and indicates you didn't just forget a comma. Compare:

```
SELECT  a b, c d, e, f, g, h i, ...

SELECT a AS b, c AS d, e, f, g, h AS i, ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the more in depth explanation

Answer (score 0):

Joining the same table twice is possible, you just have to assign a different alias to the table in each instance so that you can select columns out of the appropriate instance of the table.  Like so:

```
SELECT
    `course_main`.courseName,
    `course_prereq`.courseName AS `prereqCourseName`

FROM `course` AS `course_main`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `prereq`
ON `course_main`.courseId = `prereq`.courseId

LEFT OUTER JOIN `course` AS `course_prereq`
ON `course_prereq`.courseId = `prereq`.prereqCourseId
```

Comment: You need to take "prereqCourseId" as reference in second join to get course name according to prereqCourseId.....